# Configure a hotkey for switching viewports in Compiz?

Tags: gnome, compiz, metacity

In gconf-editor I can set hotkeys for switching to a specific workspace/viewport when using metacity. I'd like this functionality too for compiz, bit did not find it so far.
What I want is: Super-F1 switches to workspace/viewport 1, Super-F2 to workspace/viewport 2 etc.

How can I do this? (BTW: I am using ccsm with gconf-backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keybindings set in `/apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_to_workspace_X` with `gconf-editor` should continue to/also work with Compiz.  You can also use CompizConfig Settings Manager to set them.  Just select *Viewport Switcher* from the *Desktop* area, and switch to the *Go to specific viewport* tab.

(I actually set one with CCSM to verify that it still used the bindings in `/apps/metacity/`.)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Unfortunately I do not have a Viewport Switcher in the Desktop area. just "clone output", "desktop cube", "desktop wall"(enabled) and rotate cube. I'm using Fedora 14 if it's relevant. I'll look around whether there is a viewport switcher elsewhere (maybe in some exotic rpm package...)

Comment: @mawimawi:  Does manually setting the keybindings in `gconf-editor` work?  What Linux distribution/version are you running?

Comment: as written before: Fedora 14. The "Viewport switcher" was not installed on my system, I had to search for other compiz-rpms and installed compiz-fusion-extras, compiz-fusion-unsupported, compiz-fusion-extras-gnome and compiz-fusion-unsupported-gnome. Somewhere in these packages there was the Viewport Switcher, so everything's fine now. Thanks again for you info!

Comment: @mawi:  Sorry, I don't know how I missed that.  Glad you got it working!